# Unable to Collapse Pivot Table Hierarchy Connected to SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, hierarchy, tabular

I work with Excel `PivotTable` connected to an `SSAS Tabular Model`.

I am using two dimension tables, *Calendar* and *Link Number*, attached to one *Fact* table, *Sales*, that has a simple, distinct count of sales orders as a measure.

In *Calendar* table, I have built a simple **year/quarter/month** hierarchy.
In Excel, I put the *Calendar* hierarchy on *Rows*, then *Link Number* column under it, with *Sales Order Count* in *Values* area.

I want to be able to collapse everything, including the link number field, up to the year.

Here is what I have at the moment:

[Pivot table completely collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfRxW.png)

[Rows and Values layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRUc2.png)

When I put each calendar component on rows, then put Link Number under it, the table collapses as expected:

[The result I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwi6G.png)

[Rows and Values layout using calendar components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Agy.png)

I want to see the **Results I am looking for** image using the **Rows and Values layout** image.

Is this possible?